# How do I replace an element with another new element in the same index and move the previous element to the next index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have this problem where I want to replace an element with a new element, and instead of removing the element I replaced, I just want it to move to the next index.

```
import numpy as np

empty_arr = [0] * 5
arr = np.array(empty_arr)


inserted = np.insert(empty_arr, 1, 3)
inserted = np.insert(empty_arr, 1, 4) 

#Output: 
[0 4 0 0 0 0]
```

I don't know the right syntax for this but I just want to replace element **3** with **4**

```
#Expected Output:
[0 3 4 0 0 0] #move the element 4 to next index
```

Comment: `empty_arr[1] = 4`?

Comment: yes `empty_arr[1] = 4` its in index 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the result of the first insertion in the `inserted` variable but you are starting over from the original array for the 2nd insertion and overriding the previous result.

You should start the 2nd insertion from the previous result:

```
inserted = np.insert(empty_arr, 1, 3)
inserted = np.insert(inserted, 1, 4)
```

BTW, do you have to use numpy arrays for this ? regular Python lists seem better suited:

```
empty_arr = [0] * 5
empty_arr.insert(1,3)
empty_arr.insert(1,4)

print(empty_arr)

[0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

*Note that if you want 4 to appear after 3 in you result, you either have to insert them in the reverse order at index 1 or insert 4 at index 2 after inserting 3 at index 1.*

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

empty_arr = [0] * 5
arr = np.array(empty_arr)


empty_arr = np.insert(empty_arr, 1, 3)
empty_arr = np.insert(empty_arr, 1, 4) 

#output
array([0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```